# Facebook SDK login on ios

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am unable to login with facebook in my iOS app. I had thoroughly studied the Facebook api and followed the all instructions given by facebook api at developers.facebook.com site. I am able to authenticate but it is not logging in to my app. It says that Safari cannot open the page because address is invalid. I am new to iOS please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app, this is an old post but hope it is still helpful.

Comment: Thankyou very much Ishank. This link is very helpufl i solved my problem :)

Comment: thank Ray Wenderlich not me :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have skipped the part of tutorial where you add a custom url scheme to your app. Without that, Safari can't send the user back to your app once they are authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on this:

**How To Post on Facebook with Your iPhone App**

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app